# JavaScript convert with conditions

Tags: javascript

I have this code to convert input time to seconds

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('keyup', '#quizTime', function(e){
        var hms = $('#quizTime').val();
        var a = hms.split(':');
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        console.log(seconds);
    });
});
```

The problem with this code is, it expects input like `00:05:30` in order to work and won't accept if i only input minuets and seconds like `05:30` will return `NAN`

What I'm trying to find is a solution that accepts both conditions of inputs `hh:mm:ss` and also `mm:ss`

How should I change this code to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of `a`.

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('keyup', '#quizTime', function(e){
        var hms = $('#quizTime').val();
        var a = hms.split(':');
        var seconds;
        if (a.length == 3) { // hh:mm:ss
            seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        } else if (a.length == 2) { // mm:ss
            seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1]);
        } else if (a.length == 1) { // ss
            seconds = +a[0];
        } else {
            alert("That's not a valid time: " + hms);
        }
        console.log(seconds);
    });
});
```

Comment: Add more conditions with `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

Make hours default to `0` if it isnt present:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('keyup', '#quizTime', function(e){
        var hms = $('#quizTime').val();
        var a = hms.split(':');
        if(a.length !== 3) {
           a.unshift(0)
        }
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        console.log(seconds);
    });
});
```